# Sync don't goes in sync and can't fill array out DispatchQueue

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm developing some code for my App over macOS using DispatchQueue in sync
but don't know how to use it correctly.

There's a function that have to print out in order:

*response, A*

```
public func a (_ sender: AnyObject)  {
    var response: [String] = [ ]
    DispatchQueue.global().sync { // Correct
        requestUrlFunct(urlString: "https://hostname.com") { (a) in a.enumerateLines { line, _ in
                if( line != "" ){
                    response.append(line)
                        ////EDIT: here i have to populate a popup. Someting like popup?.addItem(withTitle: line) and if it's not syncronous I've got a core error
                }
            }
        print(response)
        }
    }
    print("A")
//here something like self.popup.isEnabled = true;
}
```

this function calls:

```
public func requestUrlFunct(urlString: String, completionBlock: @escaping ([Any]) -> Void) -> Void {
    let requestURL = URL(string: urlString)
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL!)

    var response: [String] = [ ]
    
    let requestTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
          let a  = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
            completionBlock([a!]);
    }
    DispatchQueue.global().sync {
        requestTask.resume()
    }
}
```

but at the end the result is:

*A, response*

Also how to fill `var response: [String] = [ ]` that's out of `DispatchQueue`? Can't fill it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping your URL calls in `DispatchQueue.global().sync` won't make the URL call actually behave synchronously -- the URL call itself will still be an asynchronous call. Which, if you think about it, is a very good thing -- we don't want our programs freezing up, if, for example, our network connection isn't responsive.

In your current code, `func a` runs, and then calls out to `requestUrlFunct`, which includes asynchronous code. That async code doesn't return automatically, so `a` keeps running and gets to your `print("A")` line. Then, the URL call returns (asynchronously) and calls your callback function (which you're passing via a trailing closure to `requestUrlFunct`). At that point, your `print(response)` line is called.

You're already making use of the concept that you'll need to use, which is "callback functions." With a callback function, you can execute some code once you get a response. **This *may* mean you have to restructure some of your code, because you won't be able to count on an immediate synchronous response.** For example, you won't be able to return your response from your `func a`.

The good news is that this will clean up some of the code you have considerably. You might notice that I use `guard` statements and `as?` to avoid force unwrapping with `!` that can cause crashes.

```
public func a (_ sender: AnyObject)  {
        requestUrlFunct(urlString: "https://hostname.com") { responseArray in
            DispatchQueue.main.async { 
              //do something with the response
            }
        }
        //can't access the response here, since it is asynchronous
    }
    
    public func requestUrlFunct(urlString: String, completionBlock: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) -> Void {
        guard let requestURL = URL(string: urlString) else {
            //handle error
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        
        let requestTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            if let data = data, let a  = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                completionBlock([a]);
            }
        }
        requestTask.resume()
    }
```

I left one artifact from the original that I'm not really sure about -- the fact that the `requestUrlFunct` callback returns a `[String]`, but it's only ever going to return one item (since the response gets turned into an array by doing `[a]`) -- this is something you might want to be looking at when you do some refactoring.

Also worth noting that most of the time with your callback functions, you also want some sort of callback to happen if there's an error. Right now, there's no error handling at all.